# winapi child frame shown inform parent

Tags: winapi

in my project (used win32 api) i need to let the parent control know when one of his children is shown/hidden. Both of their **HWND** are known.

Till now i only found the message **WM_PARENTNOTIFY** but from the [Docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this message is sent only when the children created/destructed or something with mouse actions.

As a newbee in win32 api, i have no idea further.
Any advices? thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can post or send a custom message to the parent hwnd. Messages starting at WM_APP are reserved for your app's internal use.

```
#define WM_CUSTOM_SOMETHING (WM_APP + 2)
```

Comment: thx for the reply first. i think i should describe the question more in details. i wanted to let the parent know the child visibility has changed without letting the child additionally sending a WM_CUSTOM_SOMETHING.